# How to DRY up type definitions when typing Redux action creators with Flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, flowtype

I wonder how to DRY up my type definitions. Let's explain by example:

**actions.js**

```js
export type SearchProjectsAction = {
  type: 'SEARCH_PROJECTS',
  searchString: string
}

export type SetProjectSubNavigationAction = {
  type: 'SET_PROJECT_SUB_NAVIGATION',
  options: { id: number, offset: number }
}

export type Action =
  | SearchProjectsAction
  | SetProjectSubNavigationAction

export const searchProjects = (searchString: string): SearchProjectsAction => ({
  type: 'SEARCH_PROJECTS',
  searchString
})

export const setProjectSubNavigation = (options: { id: number, offset: number }): SetProjectSubNavigationAction => ({
  type: 'SET_PROJECT_SUB_NAVIGATION',
  options
})
```

**component.js**

```js
type InputProps = {
  searchString: string
}

type Props = {
  hiddenCustomers: Array<number>,
  setProjectSubNavigation: ({ id: number, offset: number }) => void
} & InputProps

class Foo extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  ...

  onScroll() {
    this.props.setProjectSubNavigation(null)
  }
}

const FooWithData = connect(
  state => ({
    hiddenCustomers: state.projects.hiddenCustomers
  }),
  {
    setProjectSubNavigation
  }
)(Foo)

const FooWithInputProps = (props: InputProps) => (
  <FooWithData { ...props } />
)

export default FooWithInputProps
```

So since I've already typed my `setProjectSubNavigation` method, I don't want to repeat this again when typing the dispatched function in my props (like line 6 in `component.js`.

Is there any way to say something like:

```js
type Props = {
  hiddenCustomers: Array<number>,
  setProjectSubNavigation: some_type_thats_included_in_actions.js
} & InputProps
```

Comment: You can use: `typeof setProjectSubNavigation`.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! :)